# V.16.0 isn't available yet

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Why won't my minecraft pocket edition lbsg server let me go on it without updatating? All my updated have to be done in the AppStore, and that update hasn't popped up yet. Help!

Answer (score -1):

Probably because apple is confirming the update , it takes a few extra days sometimes for the App Store to update an app

Comment: Although this may be true, speculations are typically not an answer.